# output specific location in the header

Tags: wp-head

Is there a way in which I can output some code in the header and choose it's location? some where like wp function add_admin_menu (where you can choose the placement).

Comment: What do you mean by _output some code_ and what _location_? Are you talking about the backend (admin) view or frontend view?

Comment: front end view and position is just after the load jquery?

Comment: You forgot the part "ask a separate question ***with much more details***", as hinted in your previous Question...

Comment: had to break them up into two questions, don't know why the first one was closed :-(. seems its the consensus on here that if you know what you're looking for you ask a question so that someone can tell you what you already know) This ain't a place for people who are just starting out with Wordpress to further their career!

Comment: That is still not enough information, sorry. Please have a look at [Plugin API/Actions](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference#Actions_Run_During_a_Typical_Request). So, I'm guessing here: write a function that outputs your code, and hook that function to an approriate action hook. Is that what you're trying to do?

Comment: pretty much - function outputs code to the add_action(wp_head) and wanted to know if you could choose the location of where the code gets outputted inside the <head> tags

Comment: First, when writing a comment _addressed_ to a certain user, use the ´@username` function, in my case just write `@tf` in your comment. To your question, `wp_head` is not the right hook. Try `wp_print_scripts` instead. Anyway, what are you trying to do? Do you want to output some link to a CSS or JavaScript file? Please use the [`wp_enqueue_style`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style) and [`wp_enqueue_script`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) functions for that. If it it still not what you want -> output buffer and filter `wp_head`...?

Comment: @tf I want to output some jquery code and have it placed after all the meta info.

Comment: Then why don't you A) put it in a JS file and either enqueue it (with a jquery dependency) or hardcode the according `<link ... />` right after `wp_head()`, or B) hardcode the `<script> ... </script>`? Or is the content in some way dynamically generated?

Comment: it is dynamically generated, I have an options admin panel that will store the data and I need it to be entered into the header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, here is a working example of what you (might) want to do.

Put the following in your `functions.php`:

```
add_action('wp_head', 'my_jquery_code', 999999999);
function my_jquery_code() {
    $jquery_code = <<<JQUERY
<script>
    // jQuery code goes here...
</script>
JQUERY;
    echo $jquery_code.PHP_EOL;
} // function my_jquery_code
```